# What is the problem with cron privileges?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

When I run the BASH script from the command line, it is executed.
When I try to run it as a cron task, it fails. By an exception method, I found a problem. It consists in the fact that the "which iptables" command returns an empty string. This happens with all the programs that I try to find in the "/sbin" directory.
Example:

```
# crontab -e
* * * * * /root/test.sh >> /root/test.log 2>&1
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
IPT=$(which iptables);
echo ${IPT} >> /root/test.log
```

But in test.log written empty string.
Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8.

Comment: Use `IPT=$(/sbin/which iptables);`?

Comment: On my OS, the command is at "/usr/bin/which". I forgot to write that other commands, for example "which ps", return the correct result when called through cron.

Comment: It may be some permission issue. I will suggest you check `/var/log/cron` to see any error message.

Comment: Use full paths: 1. prevents such errors 2. more secure

Comment: `which` is looking in PATH. `crontab` is per user, which can have own PATH or mostly empty PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to privileges.

`which` looks for the command in `$PATH`. `cron` scripts have a limited path, that doesn't include `iptables`, so it's not found.

```
 $ /usr/bin/which iptables
/sbin/iptables
 $ PATH=/bin:/usr/bin /usr/bin/which iptables
 $ echo $?
1
```

When you have a limited path, it will return a empty string (on my other machine it reports that no iptables in (/usr/bin:/bin) so YMMV) and exit with non-zero code.

if you do something like `echo $PATH >> /root/test.log` you will see that `cron` has a path with just `/usr/bin` and `/bin`

You have to either set the `$PATH` to contain the `iptables` location, or use full path when calling `iptables`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, the directory "" is missing from "". But I was sure that the "" command is used to search for programs. Otherwise, it is easier to specify the path explicitly.

Comment: @RomanSokolov hey, did this solve your issue ? If yes please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)